# I need help to generate xml using XMLFOREST in oracle for the clob column data

Tags: xml, oracle, clob, xmlelement

I have one table with one CLOB data type and we inserted the data in that column in below format
`<ID name='BSA_NUMBER'></ID>`
and I have another few columns with `VARCHAR2(100)`.

I am trying to generate XML from the table using XMLFOREST, so the data in CLOB column is populating with
some special characters as (<ID name='BSA_NUMBER'></ID>)

The query I am using is

```c
SELECT (XMLELEMENT (
    NAME "File",
    XMLAGG (
        XMLELEMENT (
            NAME "Invoice",
            XMLFOREST (
                SHIPMENT_NUMBER AS "SHIPMENTNUMBER",
                ADDITIONAL_HEADER_INFO AS "Invoice1")))))
FROM test_xml
WHERE 1 = 1 AND CONTROL_ID = 18644;
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
   <Invoice>
      <SHIPMENTNUMBER>456</SHIPMENTNUMBER>
      <Invoice1>&lt;ID name='BSA_NUMBER'&gt;&lt;123/ID&gt;</InvoiceNumber>
   </Invoice>
</File>
```

But I need the output in the below format

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
   <Invoice>
      <SHIPMENTNUMBER>456</SHIPMENTNUMBER>
      <Invoice1><ID name='BSA_NUMBER'>123</ID></Invoice1>
   </Invoice>
</File>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Plese give code (so your output too) as text. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: SELECT (XMLELEMENT (
            NAME "File",
            XMLAGG (
                XMLELEMENT (
                    NAME "Invoice",
                    XMLFOREST (c.SHIPMENT_NUMBER AS "SHIPMENTNUMBER",
                               c.ADDITIONAL_HEADER_INFO AS "Invoice1")))))
  FROM test_xml c
 WHERE 1 = 1 AND c.CONTROL_ID = 18644;

Comment: We got the output as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
   <Invoice>
      <SHIPMENTNUMBER>456</SHIPMENTNUMBER>
      <Invoice1>&lt;ID name='BSA_NUMBER'&gt;&lt;/ID&gt;</Invoice1>
   </Invoice>
</File>

Comment: But I need the output  --> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
   <Invoice>
      <SHIPMENTNUMBER>456</SHIPMENTNUMBER>
      <Invoice1><ID name='BSA_NUMBER'>123</ID></Invoice1>
   </Invoice>
</File>